# How to resolve Error: "[object Object]" is not valid for aggregation "persoService" of ManagedObject Table personalization

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I am implementing Table personalization (sap.m.TablePersoController) that persists user-specific settings of a table on ushell services of Fiori Launchpad.

But I see below error when I run the application in Fiori Launchpad.

`Error: "[object Object]" is not valid for aggregation "persoService" of ManagedObject sap.m.TablePersoController#oTablePerso`

Could you let me know what is the issue and how to resolve it.

Below is the code for the same:

```
var oPersonalizationService= window.parent.sap.ushell.Container.getService("Personalization"); 

var oPersId = {
container : "AppPersSample2",
item : "mobiletable"
}; 

var oMobileTable = sap.ui.getCore().byId("idTable"); 

var oStartPersButton = sap.ui.getCore().byId("idButton");

var oPersonalizer = oPersonalizationService.getPersonalizer(oPersId);

console.log("oPersonalizer is:"+oPersonalizer);

// Create a table personalization controller

jQuery.sap.require("sap.m.TablePersoController");

jQuery.sap.require("sap.m.TablePersoDialog");

var oTablePersoController = new sap.m.TablePersoController("oTablePerso",{
table : oMobileTable,
persoService : oPersonalizer
});

// Use the personalization data to configure the table accordingly

oTablePersoController.activate();
```

Answer (score 1):

I don´t really know where the error is coming from, but for debugging you can split this line:

```
var oTablePersoController = new sap.m.TablePersoController("oTablePerso",{ table : oMobileTable, persoService : oPersonalizer });
```

into:

```
        var oPersonalizationService = sap.ushell.Container.getService("Personalization");
        var oProvider = sap.ushell.Container.getService("Personalization").getPersonalizer(oPersId);
        this._oTPC = new sap.m.TablePersoController({});
        this._oTPC.setPersoService(oProvider);
        this._oTPC.setTable(oMobileTable);
```

Just try and set breakpoints.

As a example, here is my full function vor my ui.table with version 1.60.5

```
        createPersonalization: function (viewName) {
        var oTable = this.table;
        // Create a persistence key
        var oPersId = {
            container: viewName,
            item: viewName
        };

        // Get a personalization service provider from the shell (or create your own)
        this.oPersonalizationService = sap.ushell.Container.getService("Personalization");
        var oProvider = sap.ushell.Container.getService("Personalization").getPersonalizer(oPersId);

        this._oTPC = new sap.ui.table.TablePersoController({
            // table: oTable,
            // persoService: oProvider
        });
        this._oTPC.setPersoService(oProvider);
        this._oTPC.setTable(oTable);
    },
```

Comment: Hi Marian, I tried your suggestion. Error is being thrown at this line: this._oTPC.setPersoService(oProvider); The error which I got earlier is still coming.

Comment: Ok, either is comming from "oPersoId", my declaration is
var oPersId = {
    container: "viewName",
    item: "viewName"
   };
Maybe you have a different version, try look at the Docs, there is a Sample too https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.TablePersoController

Comment: Hi Marian, I am not using views or components etc. There is only one index.html file, in that I have created table and want to do personalization. Could you please suggest me something. should the names in the persist key section be view name? or can it be any? Thank you.

Comment: The viewName is just a variable in my function and i use a string, just as you.
Have you tried the example in the api reference or in the examples here: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.m.Table/sample/sap.m.sample.TablePerso/code/Table.controller.js ?

Comment: Hi Marian, It seems the issue is with this line too:var oPersonalizationService= window.parent.sap.ushell.Container.getService("Personalization"); . Actually my index.html file is present inside iFrame (can't access ushell service). So, if I don't use window.parent, I see the error when I run the application in normal window. If I run the same app in Fiori launchpad, I get the error in table persocontroller section because of the same window.parent I think. Any suggestion are welcome.